# Numbered list difference between preview and final edit; doesn't start numbering again after horizontal line

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

Original text and basic preview:

[image: original+basic]

Final preview:

[image: final preview]

Result after submit (this post):

[image: result]

List numbers continued in final, but by separating with horizontal line I would like to start new list (like shown in basic preview).

1. List item

---

2. App Version: 1.6.0.10
3. Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
4. OS Version: Version 10.0.2 (Build 14A456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.1.1.

The basic (live) preview list format will be fixed to match the final preview and submitted format.  I,e., lists starting with a number greater than one will start with that number.

Support for custom start indices in Pagedown.js was added in [October 2014](https://github.com/balpha/pagedown/commit/d3dd00c4c359cf81b63fff80634c066d397af45d#diff-bfcae5a5d1ce75b91d93772e60d6ed92) and Pagedown in the app was from June 2014.

Comment: Can you clarify what will be in a result? Final like basic or basic like final?